# Convert a Unicode string to hexadecimal

Tags: sql, oracle, unicode, hex, globalization

I want to convert a Unicode string to hexadecimal.

In other words I need to convert a string like `أحمد` to:

```
0xC3CDE3CF0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
```

Comment: Don't ask the same question multiple times.  This is not a support site, we are all volunteers here and you have **no entitlement** to an immediate answer.  If you don't get a quick response you should consider whether your original question is clear and meaningful.

Comment: Voting to close your original question as a duplicate of this one as you now have answers here. As APC has said please do not do this.

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
select rawtohex(convert('أحمد','AR8ISO8859P6','AL32UTF8')) 
from dual;
```

[Here is a sqlfiddle demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d41d8/8876)

Answer (score 0):

```
select rawtohex(col) from table
```

Comment: Thanks sir for your quick response,
I tried it but it doesn't work as i am expecting
I need the resulting code as the result from MS Sql Server
in SQL: select  cast('أحمد' as binary);
Result: 0xC3CDE3CF0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
but in Oracle: select rawtohex('أحمد') from dual;
Result: D8A3D8ADD985D8AF
Surly Not matches

Comment: @AhmedShaban - This is because of different charsets - your Oracle server runs with UTF-8.  What 1-byte character set was used in your MSSQL server?

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff, just convert it to Arabic - http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d41d8/8876